# Errors in render classes in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have such code, that in the end of it all have to create figures on my chess board:

```
export class Board {
    chessBoard: HTMLCanvasElement;
    ctx: CanvasRenderingContext2D;
    squareSize: number = 80;
    letters: string[] = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h'];
    numbers: number[] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];
    pieces: IPiece[] = [];
    lightCell: string = '#efd9b7';
    darkCell: string = '#b48866';
    constructor() {
        this.chessBoard = document.getElementById('chessBoard-canvas') as HTMLCanvasElement;
        this.ctx = this.chessBoard.getContext('2d') as CanvasRenderingContext2D;
    }
   ...
  createFigure(row: number, col: number, x: number, y: number): void {
    for (const figure of this.pieces) {
        figure.image.onload = () => row === figure.row && col === figure.column ? figure.create(x, y) : null;
    }
    this.createPieces();
  }
}
```

But I have some problems like:
figure.image.onload - Object is possibly 'undefined'.ts(2532)
figure.create(x, y) - Cannot invoke an object which is possibly 'undefined'.ts(2722)

How to handle it?

IPiece interface

```
export interface IPiece {
id: number,
column: number,
row: number,
color: TColors,
name: TName,
image?: HTMLImageElement,
steps?: IStep[],
create?(row: number, column: number): void,
newSteps?(row: number, column: number): void,
```

}

Comment: show `IPiece` interface

Comment: @andymccullough added above. But if delete ? next to image and create, than I have mistakes in webpack like:
ERROR in C:\Users\DEN\Desktop\chess\src\chessGame\ts\piecesBoardPlace.ts
./src/chessGame/ts/piecesBoardPlace.ts 221:4-227:5
[tsl] ERROR in C:\User\Desktop\chess\src\chessGame\ts\piecesBoardPlace.ts(221,5)
      TS2739: Type '{ id: number; name: "queen"; color: "white"; row: number; column: number; }' is missing the following properties from type 'IPiece': image, create

Answer (score 0, accepted):

given that `image` and `create` are optional, you'll need to check for their existence, e.g.

```
for (const figure of this.pieces) {
   if(figure.image) {
      figure.image.onload = () => {
         if(row === figure.row && col === figure.column) {
            figure.create?.(x, y)
         }         
      }
   }
}
```

note also the `figure.create?.(x, y)` that only invokes `create` if it exists

also removed the ternary, as its often seen as bad practice to use a ternary as a short way of writing an `if` statement with a function invocation

Comment: yes, it works, but, unfortunately, I can't see my figures on the browser(

Comment: by 'works' do you mean it just doesn't error anymore, or is it actually calling `create`?

Comment: yea it might not error, because its not calling code that is shouldnt be, but you'll need to figure out why those values / objects were undefined in the first place

Comment: where i should call this function to render my pieces? createFigure